# Post Future? How?

Tags: php, content-management-system

I have a question.
I some CMSs, at Posting section, we have a option: "Post to future". If we check it, we can give it a date and a time for posting that article. (e.g. 1/1/2011).
And when the day comes, (1/1/2011), the CMS posts that article automatically.

How???
(Is it possible? or I thinking wrong?)

Comment: Need to clarify.  This does not seem coding related.  Looks like help with "post scheduling" for something like Wordpress or content.

Comment: Are you asking now to use a CMS or how to add this feature to one?

Comment: CMSes do not post articles. They just request them from databases. *According to some rules*

Answer (score 5):

This is very specific to whatever CMS you're using, but I'm going to guess that it simply stores the "post date", and then when asked to display all articles it does something like: `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE post_date <= NOW()`.

Comment: They would use a similar feature to expire articles.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to implement a feature like this.

I think the easiest would be to have a startTime field in your database.  When you are loading the list of articles, you can do `WHERE startTime < NOW()`.  This will make it so articles only show up after the designated time.

You could also use cron or a number of other methods.

Comment: Presumably you mean `WHERE startTime < NOW()`, not `>`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends.

In many cases, it's simply a matter of not-published-yet articles not appearing anywhere (search results, main page, archives...) which can be done by storing a publishing date in the article table and testing it:

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE publishDate < NOW()
```

However, it's quite frequent that some tasks must be performed at the exact moment where the article is published (such as pingbacks/trackbacks, sending e-mails to subscribers...) and the solution for that is to have a scheduled task run every so often (for instance, every five minutes) that queries the database for any unpublished articles that have their publishing date in the past, and does whatever is necessary to publish them.

Comment: Should be a LT comparison, not GT.